# Azure Synapse - Github personal access token is invalid

Tags: azure, github, azure-synapse

I have linked a github repo to an Azure synapse account, and all the resources, pipelines, data flows, etc are successfully committed in ARM files in the repo

However, when another developer tries to access this synapse workspace he gets the following error "Retrieve GitHub Access Token - The personal access token is invalid. Please provide a valid token"

When he logs into github through synapse, he is never prompted to enter his PAT. He has full ownership rights on the github repo and is an admin on the Azure subscription and owner of the synapse workspace

[image]

Comment: Have you granted access for user in synapse access control, in a role, like synapse artefact user?

Comment: yes, the user is an owner of the synapse workspace

Answer (score 0):

We figured this out with help from Microsoft support - turns out it was nothing to do with personal access tokens and was just a permissions issue in Azure, when I made the other developer a Synapse Administrator.

The key was to make him a Synapse Administrator from *within* the workspace itself (under the manage tab) as opposed to an owner of the workspace, set within Azure portal:

[image]